# Understanding some Antidebug inline asm for Windows / MSVC in C/C++

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to understand some of the anti-debugger functions in https://github.com/nemesisqp/al-khaser/blob/0f74c40dde8ba060807e031271f81457a187fa08/DebuggerDetection.cpp#L603

---

Would

```
__asm {
    mov eax, fs:[30h]
    mov al, [eax + 2h]
    mov IsDbg, al
}
```

function the same as

```
__asm mov IsDbg, [fs:[0x30] + 0x2]
```

If not, why not?

Also, how could this be converted to pure C/C++? How can I get thread info (specifically fs:[30h])?

---

And would

```
BOOL Int2DCheck()
{
    // The Int2DCheck function will check to see if a debugger
    // is attached to the current process. It does this by setting up
    // SEH and using the Int 2D instruction which will only cause an
    // exception if there is no debugger. Also when used in OllyDBG
    // it will skip a byte in the disassembly and will create

    __try
    {
        __asm
        {
            int 2dh
            xor eax, eax
            add eax, 2
        }
    }
    __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Be the same as

```
__try
{
    __asm
    {
        xor eax, eax
        int 0x2d
        inc eax
    }
}
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
{
    return false;
}
```

If not, why not?

Comment: `mov IsDbg, [fs:[0x30] + 0x2]` has 2 memory operands, and thus is not encodeable.  Also the source addressing mode isn't encodeable; x86 machine code doesn't have double-indirect addressing modes.  (x86 asm is just a text representation of x86 machine code, so every instruction can assemble to a single machine instruction.)

Comment: okay @PeterCordes, regarding the `mov al, [ eax + 2h ]`\n`mov bDebuggerPresence, al`, would it work as `mov bDebuggerPresence, [ eax + 2h ]`? and would the other `int 0x2d` op work in c/c++ as posted?

Comment: No, `int 0x2d` is a system call (but you haven't set the input registers for it, so that makes no sense as a snippet without more context).  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/INTn:INTO:INT3:INT1.html.  You're on Windows, so the `int ??` system-call ABI isn't stable or officially documented, and can change with updates / service packs.

Comment: @Steve it's antidebug stuff, so I can't exactly test it and know for certain it works.

Comment: @PeterCordes that is all the context i have. https://github.com/nemesisqp/al-khaser/blob/0f74c40dde8ba060807e031271f81457a187fa08/DebuggerDetection.cpp#L603

Comment: @CryptographyMan I am admittedly naive on this subject. Wouldn't a test be "debug it and see what happens", or does that not work?

Comment: @Steve nope! :) As I understand it, if you attach a debugger to see how it's working, then it shouldn't work. If you don't attach a debugger, then you won't see if it's working.

Comment: That's the point right?

Comment: Attach debugger see it fail, see it run without. Again I'm naive...

Comment: Ah, I suppose it could silently corrupt something somehow and be UB...

Comment: @Steve yeah, that's why I'm trying to see if someone can explain the functionality behind it so I can actually properly implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of those techniques are relatively old.  I think they were in use in the early 2000s, if not the late 90s.

---

The first uses the fact that the [Thread-Information Block (TIB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) resides at `fs:[0]` for windows processes (at least as late as WinXP...I haven't looked since then).

Offset 0x30 into the TIB is a pointer to the [Process Environment Block (PEB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/ns-winternl-_peb).  From that link, we see that offset 0x2 into the PEB is the 'being debugged' flag.  This is the value that is read by the API call `IsDebuggerPresent`.

---

The second example demonstrates two detection mechanisms:

[This answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/int-2d-anti-forensic-method/1544) gives good detail on the function of `int 0x2d` on windows.  For the moment, we'll just note that it's part of Windows' built-in debugging support.

The simpler mechanism is this: Structured exception handling in Windows would catch things that the language-based exceptions couldn't, because it was hooked into the OS's exception handling framework, not the language-runtime's.

So the `int 0x2d` would generate a fault; any debugger present would handle the fault, and because this interrupt is for debugging, the debugger would return to control-flow as usual.  Thus the structured-exception handling mechanism wouldn't be invoked...so the 'catch' would never be reached, and the return value of the function would thereby change.  This method was pretty trivially defeated by later SEH-aware debuggers, by telling the debugger to pass the exception to the program, in which case the SEH would fire.

The other mechanism is based in the detail of the of way `int 0x2d` is processed by windows, which was apparently not emulated perfectly by OllyDbg (a once phenomenal debugger that went defunct and came back full of malware).  I am not personally familiar with this method, so I would direct you to the linked answer.

Just for context, the early days of anti-debugger techniques were studies of particularly popular debug tools.  In whatever document you've dug these techniques from, you will no doubt also see ones dedicated to detecting NuMega Softice --- probably the first kernel debugger for Windows (circa NT 4.0).  The instruction sequence from whence my handle is derived was used as a method of detecting this debugger.

Thanks for the trip down memory lane ;)

Comment: How does this ( https://github.com/LordNoteworthy/al-khaser/blob/71692a5847dea9448ab7ae65b90511b7ef7f2f9b/al-khaser/Anti%20Debug/Interrupt_0x2d.cpp#L32 ) differ from the example in the question?

Comment: Similar mechanism: rather than using MSVC's syntax of `__try`/`__except` to do it automatically, that code manually builds the SEH chain using WinAPI calls.  Note that the function sets the flag 'swallowedException` to `true`, and the handler function sets it back to `false` if it fires.  "Vectored Exceptions" are an extension of SEH.

Comment: So to clarify, the handler setting swalledException to false means a debugger is present?

Comment: no, the opposite.  If a debugger is present, the debugger swallows the exception, so the handler never fires.

Comment: ah! now it makes sense. i was wondering why you would default it to true :p Thanks for the help! Might I ask where you got your education? I'm really interested in topics like these, and im starting my senior year for my computer science degree and have learned nothing like this/interesting so far :/

Comment: Heh. I discovered `Fravia's pages of reverse-engineering` as a freshman in 1995.  There are still a [few archives](http://www.woodmann.com/fravia/student.htm) of it around...  Note that this was before DMCA, so cracking shareware was a much more common hobby. That led to a career defending software for about 5 years. Fortunately, the DMCA has an exception for academic use, so long as your work does not damage the company whose products you investigate...

Comment: Yeah, of course not! I would never, nor do I have the ability to harm any company with my reverse engineering "skills". I'll take a look at those archives, thanks for everything